# C#, UWP Application : Unable to bind data from API to listview

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I am trying to display list of data from api to listview in UWP application.

Please find below my XAML code:

```
<ListView Name="course_list_view" Margin="-167,389,167,389" ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding avatar}" Width="32" Height="32"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding subject_name}" Foreground="Teal" FontSize="14" 
                                Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Please find my code below:

```
private async Task GetAssignCourse()
        {
            string id = localSettings.Values[appconstant.ID].ToString();
            AssignCourseService assignCourseDetail = new AssignCourseService();
            courseList = await assignCourseDetail.getAssignCourse(id);
            //for (int i = 0; i < courseList.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    Assignedcourselist assignedcourselist = courseList[i];


            //}
            course_list_view.ItemsSource = courseList;
            //course_list_view.DisplayMemberPath = "subject_name";

        }
```

I am unable to display the list I am getting from API to list. 
Can you please help me and let me know the mistake I am doing.
I am very new to coding, so please help

Comment: Have you tried using the ListView.Items collection?

Comment: Yes, i used Observable Collection
static ObservableCollection<Assignedcourselist> courseList = new ObservableCollection<Assignedcourselist>();

Comment: Use {x:Bind avatar} and {x:Bind subject_name}. And remove the full stop from your itemsSource binding. If this doesn't fix your issue then x:Bind will atleast give you run-time validation which will be helpful when debugging.

Comment: Oh, and you can try to add `Bindings.Update();` after your ObservableCollection has updated, in order to manually prompt your ListView to update its ItemsSource. These are all things that you can try, but if nothing works then we'll need to have a look at your ObservableCollection too

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think this may be the binding source was not updated in a timely manner.

First, please check the following:

1. The result from `assignCourseDetail.getAssignCourse (id);` is a type inherited from `ICollection` (such as `List` or `ObservableCollection`)
2. Does the data structure `courseList` gets contains the properties you bound in the `DataTemplate`

Second, if these are normal, you can choose the following two options to try:

**1. Binding data sources in XAML**

**XAML**

```xml
<ListView Name="course_list_view" Margin="-167,389,167,389" ItemsSource="{Binding courseList}"
          ...
          >
       ...
</ListView>
```

**XAML.cs**

```cs
var result = await assignCourseDetail.getAssignCourse(id);
courseList.Clear();
foreach(var item in result)
{
    courseList.Add(item);
}

// No need set the ItemsSource
// course_list_view.ItemsSource = courseList;
```

If `courseList` is `ObservableCollection`, then this way can be used. Because `ObservableCollection` inherits the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, it will notify the UI to change when the collection item changes.

---

**2. Change the value of ItemsSource once**

First remove the binding value of `ListView.ItemsSource` in XAML.

Secondly, modify the value of ItemsSource in Code-behind

```cs
courseList = await assignCourseDetail.getAssignCourse(id);
course_list_view.ItemsSource = null;
course_list_view.ItemsSource = courseList;
```

`courseList` as a data source, is externally defined. If we want the data changes trigger UI changes, we need to change the value of `ListView.ItemsSource` once, so the data changes will be notified to the UI.

Best regards.